# Unable to connect android socket connection over Cellular network

Tags: android, sockets, networking, tcp, udp

I am working on Android chat project. I have managed to build chat application which can handle text, file exchange and audio call using TCP Socket and UDP Datagramsocket connection. Every thing is working fine on local network but when I try to use cellular data it fails.

I am not much more familiar with the networking background but if it work on my local network then it should work on cellular network as it is a part of big network with some securities. I need help to figure out where I am doing mistake and how can i manage to resolve them.

In my project I am using port 80,1234,50002,50001,50003,8555,8553,8080 to communicate between client and server on TCP and UDP. On my local network I have no security so all ports are open for me locally but on cellular network may be these ports are not open. For this issue, how can I find the open ports on cellular network? Or is there any other alternative to use socket connection over cellular network.

Thank you

Comment: You can't open ports on a cellular network.  They're blocked by the telecom provider, who isn't overly likely to open them.  Really you need to write phone apps with the assumption that you're not going to be able to open up a listening socket.

Comment: Mobile apps can make outgoing TCP connections over a cellular network, but they usually cannot receive incoming TCP connections, or incoming UDP packets unless outgoing UDP packets are sent first. For P2P over cellular, you typically need a public central server on the Internet to act as a proxy between clients.

Comment: I started to build app for local network and had not faced this issue, after switching to cellular data I had faced this problem. Now I want to figure out the way to use this app on cellular network, apart from the firewall and closed ports I just have to figure out some alternative way. I know that I can't open the port on cellular network. But if I get information of which ports are open on Cellular network then I can modify my app to those ports. Or still if doesn't work what are the other alternative available to make socket connection work over cellular network.